# How to get value of font padding and edittext padding above?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have 2 multi line `EditText` with 2 lines of text entered as shown in images below.

Edittext 1:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

[image: Edittext 1]

EditText 2:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:includeFontPadding="true"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

[image: Edittext 2]

I have two questions..

1. The first `EditText` has fixed height 30dp and contains a fixed space above line "ASDFGHJKL...". How can i get the value of this space?
2. Secondly, how can i get the value of fontpadding, when `android:includeFontPadding` is set to true.?

Comment: Why do you need that paddings of edittext? They are default

Comment: Im not going to change them. I need the values for placing a view over it.

Answer (score 1):

@DevMarc

**Question 1:**
Idea is Android has options to have multi line text views, it seems you have forced it to be single line.

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Please try using something like this:

```
android:lines="2"
```

Ref: [Android Developer Site for Multiple Lines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lines)

If you interested in adding ellipses use this:

```
android:ellipsize="1"
```

Ref: Please find the link in comments as with my profile can't post more than two links.

**Question 2**
Try this :

```
textview.getPaint().getFontSpacing()
```

Ref: [Get Paint method for textview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getPaint())

Hope it helps.

Comment: Link for ellipsizing it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

Comment: Thanks for your response. What im trying to achieve is to place a view over certain portion of text. The problem is i dont have enough values for calculation. For instance, the space im asking about.

Comment: Is it that you are trying to have some ***** for password kind of field?